# How can I detect when the boot sequence is complete on headless system

Tags: 14.04, boot, server, bash

I have a CONF file in /etc/init to configure and start software on my headless machine.  When a monitor is attached for development and testing I see that my software starts near the end of the boot sequence when (non existent) network connections are being searched for.  The boot pauses a bit and then prints a message that it will wait up to 60 seconds more.  After 60 seconds the boot sequence continues, my software fails, and Ubuntu asks for log in.

My workaround for testing is to add a sleep 150 to the bash script that is started but I'd rather have the script detect when the boot is indeed complete then use a magic number.

Is there any way of doing this in a script?  (I'm not proficient with LINUX BTW.)

EDIT
My computer does have two NICs. LAN1 connects directly to a research grade IR camera and uses UDP for communications. LAN0 connects to a router to allow a user to load a webpage to control the camera from the computer over WiFi.  Except when developing, testing, or debugging the router does not connect to any external network.

/etc/init/fireimager.conf

```
description "Copies fireimager executables to the ram disk and executes them."
author "Robert Lockwood"

#start on filesystem or runLevel [2345]
start on net-device-added INTERFACE=eth0
stop on shutdown

script
    exec /home/programmer/bin/init/inittest
    echo "[`date`] Fireimager Suite Started" >> /var/log/fireimager.log

end script
```

/home/programmer/bin/init/inittest

```
#!/bin/bash
# programs to run as user programmer

su -c "/home/programmer/bin/provisionServer" programmer password -
sleep 130
su -c "/home/programmer/bin/startAPI &" programmer password -
su -c "/home/programmer/bin/startServer &" programmer password -
su -c "/home/programmer/bin/startController &" programmer password -
```

Comment: Have you tried commenting out `auto eth0` in /etc/network/interfaces so that non-existent network connections do not unnecessarily delay the boot process?

Comment: show your upstart config please

Comment: I've added the contents of the files that I think you asked for.

Comment: **Old fart alert!** What you're asking for is similar to "I want my program to be the last line in `AUTOEXEC.BAT`" which in a single-user single-tasking machine is OK, but in a multi-user multi-tasking OS isn't ideal...  Instead of forcing the OS to adhere to what you want, you need to change your software to sleep.  E.G. do a `while` `try` in your Software's init procedure (as it looks like you're the developer anyway)...  ;-)

Comment: For technical reasons I need to control this in my initialization *script* and what I would like to do is the equivalent to a while(foo) try loop but I'm asking for help with the condition I'm testing in the while(foo).  This is not equivalent to placing the execution of a program last in in AUTOEXEC.BAT.  By the time DOS arrived I had been programming for about 6 years but I've been using LINUX for only about 3 years now. Your comment is not especially helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This will stop the network manager looking for any network.  But any connection previously found will still work.

```
sudo su
echo manual >> /etc/init/network-manager.override
```

or in your config change your start to

```
start on net-device-added INTERFACE!=lo
```

or

```
start on net-device-added INTERFACE=eth0 (eth0 or what ever connection you have)
```

Comment: I've added the contents of the fireimager.conf file edited with your suggestion.  I'll now test it.

Comment: That did not work. I set up my network manually so don't think network-manager is running is that's what's used to setup a network using a GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command as root (or with sudo):

`systemctl is-system-running`

While still booting up, the output will be `starting`.

When it's done booting up, the output will be `running`.